# Extract rows with min or max value from a Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, extract, min

Im working on a crash course for R at https://bioinformatics-core-shared-training.github.io/r-crash-course/crash-course.nb.html

The problem im facing is to extract rows that are min or max for a certain value.

For example, when running

```
df[df$tmp ==min(df$tmp),]
```

I get the correct row with the expected value.

However, when running the following code

```
df[min(df$tmp),]
```

I get something else completely.

Im wondering what is causing this discrepancy?

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer. However, the correct approach is a bit weird  since there is a lot of redundancy in the code! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df$Tmp` is numeric with no NAs, `min(df$Tmp)` should be returning a number.  Assuming that number is an integer, i, `df[min(df$Tmp),]` will return the ith row of your data frame, assuming that your data frame has an ith row.

On the other hand, `df[df$Tmp ==min(df$tmp),]` will return the row(s) of df where `df$Tmp` is equal to the minimum value in that column.

Answer (score 0):

`df[df$Tmp ==min(df$tmp),]` is the correct approach to get what you are looking for.

`df[min(df$Tmp),]` returns the row in `df` that is equal to `min(df$Tmp)`. It may result in an error in certain cases for e.g. when `min(df$Tmp)` is not an integer, or is negative, or if it is greater than the number of rows in `df` etc. Hope this makes sense.